# Issues with PowerShell Web Access Authentication Type set as CredSSP

Tags: iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell-remoting, credssp

When setting up PowerShell Web Access authentication, by default it uses "Default" as authentication type. I set up CredSSP and it works fine for network authentication. However, I want CredSSP to be default mode of authentication instead "Default". I looked deeply into the configuration for PSWA web in IIS, I see there several values available that override the defaults. defaultAuthentcationType is seen set to 0 which is the right settings. On the web page I can see the select box has the following options

```
0   Default
1   Basic
2   Negotiate
4   CredSSP
5   Digest
6   Kerberos
```

`3 is missing` on the list. My research confirmed that the 3 is NegotiateWithImplicitCredential which is missing on my PowerShell 5.1.15063.966. So when I set defaultAuthenticationType to a number, then the web page defaults to a new option: `7   Admin Specified`

When I tried 3 and 4, neither one works with CredSSP. It is just Kerberos I keep getting even when i set defaultAuthenticationType to CredSSP, no Admin option appears and it goes back to Default again.

Anyone with similar experience like this should please share what I can do to use CredSSP

Comment: could you please share how are you changing the authentication?

Comment: I use this command winrm get winrm/config/service

Comment: try to run the command `Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site/pswa'  -filter "appSettings/add[@key='defaultAuthenticationType']" -name "value" -value "4"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by your scenario, try these few steps

On your local machine

```
PS C:\> Enable-WSManCredSSP -DelegateComputer [ComputerName] -Role Client
```

Next, You need to enable the server side.

```
PS C:\> invoke-command {enable-wsmancredssp -Role Server -Force} -ComputerName [ComputerName]
```

With this in place, you can now re-establish your remote session specifying CredSSP and your credentials.

```
PS C:\> enter-pssession [ComputerName] -Authentication Credssp -Credential domain\user
```

Run this authorization command and it would authorize you using CredSSP

```
PS C:\> Add-PswaAuthorizationRule -rulename "Rule01" -computername [computerName] -username domain\user -configuration microsoft.powershell
```

Use PS `C:\> Get-PswaAuthorizationRule` to verify the rule.